# Update and calculate value through SQL Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, cursor

I have two columns (**TSD_BALANCEUNITS and TSD_UNITSINCERT**). **TSD_BALANCEUNITS** has numeric values and **TSD_UNITSINCERT** has 0.00

By using cursor I want to update values of **TSD_BALANCEUNITS** to **TSD_UNITSINCERT** until the total sum of values updated in from **TSD_BALANCEUNITS** to **TSD_UNITSINCERT** is equal to 199.00

and the values of **TSD_BALANCEUNITS** which is being updated becomes 0.00 and moved to **TSD_UNITSINCERT** when total sum of moved values is equal to **199.00**

Below is the script that I am using ...

```
        DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;
        DECLARE @TSD_BALANCEUNITS AS DECIMAL(25, 4)
        DECLARE @TSD_UNITSINCERT AS DECIMAL(25, 4)
        DECLARE @CHECKFLAG AS DECIMAL(25, 4)
        DECLARE LOCK_CERT_UNITS CURSOR LOCAL STATIC
        FOR

        SELECT TSD_BALANCEUNITS
            ,TSD_UNITSINCERT
        FROM IS_TRX_TRX_PROCESSED
        WHERE (TSD_ACCCODE = 8775)
            AND TSD_BALANCEUNITS > 0
        ORDER BY TSD_REALIZEDDATE ASC


        OPEN LOCK_CERT_UNITS

        FETCH NEXT
        FROM LOCK_CERT_UNITS
        INTO @TSD_BALANCEUNITS
            ,@TSD_UNITSINCERT

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 --AND @cnt < 199.00
        BEGIN
            SET @TSD_UNITSINCERT = @TSD_BALANCEUNITS
            SET @CHECKFLAG = + @TSD_BALANCEUNITS

            IF (SUM(@CHECKFLAG) <= 199.00)
            BEGIN
                UPDATE IS_TRX_TRX_PROCESSED
                SET TSD_UNITSINCERT = TSD_BALANCEUNITS
                WHERE (TSD_ACCCODE = 8775)
                    AND TSD_BALANCEUNITS > 0
            END

            PRINT 'BALANCE UNIT =' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @TSD_BALANCEUNITS) + ' ==> ' + 'CERT IN UNITS =' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @TSD_UNITSINCERT);

            FETCH NEXT
            FROM LOCK_CERT_UNITS
            INTO @TSD_BALANCEUNITS
                ,@TSD_UNITSINCERT
        END

        CLOSE LOCK_CERT_UNITS

        DEALLOCATE LOCK_CERT_UNITS
        GO
```

[image: **TSD_BALANCEUNITS and TSD_UNITSINCERT**]

Comment: Can you please put the input data in a sql query to work

Comment: you have not added the table structure please add all relevant information so that some can take a look on the problem.

Comment: Both columns are,  decimal(24, 8)

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The Script is updating the records from one column to another but i can not figure out the way to stop it when the updated total is equal to 199.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command:

```
UPDATE IS_TRX_TRX_PROCESSED
SET    TSD_UNITSINCERT = TSD_BALANCEUNITS
WHERE  (TSD_ACCCODE = 8775)
AND    TSD_BALANCEUNITS > 0
```

update all records where TSD_ACCCODE = 8775 and TSD_BALANCEUNITS > 0, it doesn't matter if its sum 999, you need to identify in some way wich records must be updated.

Second, according the result, this never happens. That means that `IF (SUM(@CHECKFLAG) <= 199.00)` is never true. I suppose because you never initializes it value to 0.

```
SET @CHECKFLAG = 0;
```

Comment: Yes, the problem was with the `@CHECKFLAG`. After some changes in where clause the script was refined more ... but the issue was with the flag. As the the flag wasn't initialized to 0. Thus not getting the values properly.